# RxJs - How to implement parallel HTTP requests when you have a variable number of requests to make

Tags: node.js, express, rxjs, reactive-programming

I am developing a Node.js API with Express, using the node-rest-client module to make http requests.

One of the API endpoints to develop is `/api/v1/users/:userId` that returns the full information of a user, its user info plus the detailed information about the departments he belongs to.

To get the information there are this backend REST services:

`/users/:userId` - Returns a JSON object with the user info plus the list of department ids, e.g.:

```
{ "name" : "xxx",
  "departments" : [1, 5 ,6, 8]
}
```

`/departments/:departmentId` - JSON object with the department info

```
{ 
  "id" : x,
  "name" : "xxx"
}
```

An invocation to `/api/v1/users/1`would need to call

1. `GET /user/1` -> `{ "name" : "user1" , "departments" : [1, ,5 ,7 ,8]}`
2. Get the department ids and make n calls to `/departments/deparmentId`
3. After all the calls, compose the full JSON response and return it.

I would like to paralellize the requests using RxJs, so I guess it would be enough with using `Rx.Observable.zip()`.

The point is, if I have an array of Observables, whose size is not fixed, representing every HTTP request call, how can I invoke `Observable.zip()`?

If the number of elements in the array where fixed I woud do it like this:

```
var observables = [ obs1, obs2 ];

Rx.Observable.zip( observables[0], observable[1], function(...){...});
```

But I don't know how many observables there are, so how can I call zip()?

Comment: Maybe combine observables with http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `...` operator from es6,

```
var observables = [obs1, obs2, obs3, ...,  obsx];
Rx.Observable.zip(...observables, function() {});
```

Comment: Cool! I'm gonna try it

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `forkJoin` that can receive observables as **array**

`Rx.Observable.forkJoin([obs1, ..., obsN]).subscribe(...);`